# Reading a pointer

Tags: c

I have a vector 
`int a[100]`.
I have read the vector and gave it the values `1,2,3`.
Now i want to use a pointer 
`int *pa=&a[100]`.
My question is can I read the pointer via `scanf` and give the `vector a[100]` some new values?

i have tried doing this:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[i])
}
```

for the vector and for the pointer:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&pa)
}
```

This is my main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int a [100],n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&pa);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",pa);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`printf("%d",pa)` is giving me 999 and the vector a still has the values `1,2,3`.

Comment: If `pa` is a pointer, then `&pa` is a pointer *to the pointer*. I.e. `&pa` points to the variable `pa`.

Comment: `printf("%d", pa);` does not make sense. Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: That for loop cannot possibly compile, sitting in global context as it is. Furthermore, there is no `pa` declared in any of this code. So perhaps post some real code as a [mcve]. Regarding "i want to use a pointer int *pa=&a[100].", you sure about that? That would sit `pa` on the one-past address fo the array and its use is pretty limited there.

Comment: you can put values to your array by scanf("%d",&(a[i])) or scanf("%d",a+i)

Comment: You need to update your code. Currently there is no defined variable with name `pa` inside `main`

Comment: The `for` loops reading `pa` and printing `pa` make no sense as you use the same variable (whether correct or not) for each iteration.

Comment: a[100] is **just outside of the array - buffer overflow**. You must not write anything to a[100], since you will definitely break something in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

The following code illustrates that `pa` points to an object and that `*pa` designates the object.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    //  Set size of array.
    static const int N = 100;

    //  Define array.
    int a[N];

    //  Initialize array.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        a[i] = i+1;

    //  Define a pointer and initialize it to point to element a[0].
    int *pa = &a[0];

    /*  Scan as if "34" were in the input.  Observe that we pass pa, not &pa.
        &pa is the address of pa.  pa is the value of pa.  Its value is the
        address of a[0].
    */
    sscanf("34", "%d", pa);

    //  Print a[0].  This will be "34".
    printf("%d\n", a[0]);

    /*  Print *pa.  Note that we use *pa, which is the object pa points to.
        That objects is a[0], so the result is "34".
    */
    printf("%d\n", *pa);

    /*  Change pa to point to a different element.  Note that we use "pa =
        address" to set the value.  This is different from the initialization,
        which had "int *pa = value".  That is because declarations need the
        asterisk to describe the type, but an assignment just needs the name;
        it does not need the asterisk.
    */
    pa= &a[4];

    //  Print *pa.  Since pa now points to a[4], this will print "5".
    printf("%d\n", *pa);
}
```